Crystal Report for Cityworks: Comments
I am using Crystal Reports 2016 and Cityworks 15.7.5 (not sure the Cityworks version is relevant)
What I am attempting to do is write a report that traps all of the Cityworks Service Requests initiated by scf, 311 that have never had a "To SCF:" comment.
I can get all comments containing "To SCF:" but I don't need to know when people are doing things correctly. I need to know when nobody has responded back to the citizen reporter in 311. I don't really even need to see the commenst just the service request numbers that have never had a "To SCF:" comment.

If the "To_SCFcomment" column is in a table that is already in the report, you can simply add
IsNull({TableName.To_SCFcomment})

as a record selection formula.
Otherwise, add the table to the report. If no comment means no record in a related table, use Outer Join.
